# Java or PHP Applet to download groups of files from Amazon S3

Tags: java, php

I have a website that provides a photo service for clients. I want to use Amazon S3 as the storage space for all the photos but am having trouble interacting with the S3 buckets. What I need to do is give my customers access to all their photos sitting in their S3 bucket. I'd like to give them a visual display of all the images and then allow them to select a group or all of the photos for download. I'm assuming a Java applet is needed to handle this interaction. Does anyone know of a java based downloader that will interface with S3 or could possibly build one?

We've also thought of all or a group of files that reside on S3 but can't figure out how to zip files while they're on S3.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose when you mean by java based downloader you're talking about web services, sincerely I don't know much about Amazon S3 web services, but I do know they exist, and what I'd advise is to first get to know the Amazon web services, try to find if there is any web method to download the files (my bet is that it has to be a bit per bit download)
Concerning java applet you would only need it if you want to upload files, because of the existing security.

Comment: We have investigated the web services and you're right, each file would need to be downloaded individually. We're looking for some interface that will download each file in sequence to a directory on the users computer, without having to click a download link each time.